# Is it good idea to use uint instead of int as the primary key in data model class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We know that the primary keys are usually positive integers.

Is it good idea to use `uint` instead of `int` as the primary key in data model class?

**Example**:

```
public class Customer
{
   public uint CustomerId {get;set;}
   //others are omitted for the sake of simplicity.
}
```

Comment: You're too optimistic thinking that 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is not enough for you ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Don't think of it. It is beyond my imagination.

Comment: @Recycle Bin: then there is no difference.

Comment: @zerkms: I change to `uint` to make it more pragmatic.

Comment: @Recycle Bin: then it's worth to change if 2,147,483,647 is too few.

Comment: @Recycle Bin: It's not realy pragmatic, more pragmatic is to use int type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The corresponding SQL data type is a signed number, so I'd stick with the `int` to avoid any surprises.

Comment: Can we change the corresponding SQL data type to uint?

Comment: @Recycle Bin: Not that I'm aware of, and I'm not sure why you'd want to. If you really need more than 2 billion numbers, you could always switch to bigint, or consider something like UniqueIdentifier.

Answer (score 10):

In case somebody else stumbles on this question - don't use `uint` for your keys. I've just tried that with Entity Framework 6.1.12 and code kept failing with cryptic "Entity doesn't have key" exception.

Only after I've changed uint property back to int it started working as expected.

So, yeah, it sucks to have 2+ billion range unused, but that's how things are. And if you have even a slight doubt that you may end up with billion plus records, go with long. Ironically, then you'll have 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 numbers unused ;).

Answer (score 8):

uint is not [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.85).aspx), so it's generally recommended not to use it in public APIs.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's bad idea, cause of int type is more optimized for using in .NET Framework.

Comment: So what will you do to handle more than `int.MaxValue`  customers?

Comment: @Recycle Bin: If I had more than 2 billion customers, the question of using a signed vs. unsigned int for the key would not be anywhere near the top of my list of concerns. And if it was, there's always long/bigint.

Comment: The one practice that I'd strongly recommend against is using a short anywhere for a key.  A good (and very smart) friend of mine did that once, under the highly realistic assumption that a particular performance-critical table could never have anything approaching 2^16 records.  A couple of database refactors later, some growth in the business, and the table in question was bumping up against that limit.  Because of the volume of the data, and key propagation, it took a dozen people a month to migrate that one column to an int.

Comment: @Recycle Bin: It's another case and if the question was about large number of customer I would answered 'YES'.