# Entity Framework code-first, error: "EntityType 'OfferSequence' has no key defined"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code-first.
I am trying to create a new entity called OfferSequence, so that the table is automatically created in the database.

The problem is that when I try to update the database with the new entity, I get the following error

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> ERP.EnterpriseDataAccessLayer.EnterpriseData.OfferSequence: :
>   EntityType 'OfferSequence' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType. OfferSequences: EntityType: EntitySet 'OfferSequences' is
>   based on type 'OfferSequence' that has no keys defined.

However, as you can see below, the key is clearily defined on the property SequenceStart

```
public class OfferSequence : IEntity<OfferSequence>
{
    public OfferSequence(uint sequenceStart, uint incrementalCounter, uint annualIncrementalCounter)
    {
        Validate.EnsureIsTrue(incrementalCounter >= sequenceStart && annualIncrementalCounter >= sequenceStart, "Counters can not be lower than sequence start");

        SequenceStart = sequenceStart;
        IncrementalCounter = incrementalCounter;
        AnnualIncrementalCounter = annualIncrementalCounter;
        LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    [Key]
    public uint SequenceStart { get; private set; }

    public uint IncrementalCounter { get; private set; }

    public uint AnnualIncrementalCounter { get; private set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; private set; }

    public OfferSequence Clone()
    {
        OfferSequence copy = new OfferSequence(SequenceStart, IncrementalCounter, AnnualIncrementalCounter);

        return copy;
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone();
    }

    public void Modify(OfferSequence obj)
    {
        AnnualIncrementalCounter = obj.AnnualIncrementalCounter;
        IncrementalCounter = obj.IncrementalCounter;
        LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have no parameterless constructor, not sure EF can handle this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you cannot use an unsigned int as a key in Entity Framework: I don't have anything official that says this, but an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918106/is-it-good-idea-to-use-uint-instead-of-int-as-the-primary-key-in-data-model-clas) suggests it, as does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303631/how-to-use-unsigned-int-long-types-with-entity-framework).

Edit: actually [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1489) is an official word from the EF team regarding this. Here's what they said:

> EF Team Triage: Unsigned integers are not supported by EFs internal
>   model that it uses to store metadata. We should consider supporting
>   them, or having a way to deal with types that aren't explicitly
>   supported.
>
> The error message could definitely be improved here and is a symptom
>   of our rule that Code First just ignores any properties of unsupported
>   types. We could detect this situation and provide a better message.
>
> Given where we are in the EF6 release we aren't going to change
>   anything now. Moving to Future to consider for upcoming releases.