# What can cause an Entity Type has no key defined error besides having no key defined?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've done extensive research on this error I'm getting:

```
EntityType 'Todo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

Both here and on other websites:

1. [EntityType has no key defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203492/entitytype-has-no-key-defined-error)
2. https://gilesey.wordpress.com/tag/entitytype-has-no-key-defined/
3. [Entity type has no key defined EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205961/entity-type-has-no-key-defined-ef6)

etc...

However, I am not having the same problem as these askers. The problem that they had is that they failed to identify a primary key in their model, I have not. See below:

Model:

```
namespace TaskMaster.Library.Models
{
    public enum Priority
    {
        Highest = 0,
        High = 1,
        Medium = 2,
        Low = 3,
        Lowest = 4
    }
    public class Todo 
    {
        [Key]
        public uint Id { get; set; }
        public ITask Task { get; set; }
        public bool isDone { get; set; }
        public bool isVisible { get; set; }

        public Priority Priority { get; set; }

    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
namespace TaskMaster.Library.Models
{
    class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext()
            :base ("DefaultConnection")
            {
                this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            }

        public virtual DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }

        }
}
```

What I've tried (besides reading the articles):

1. Changing the Id name to TodoId.
2. Adding [Key]
3. Double checking the DbSet and DBContext

However, EF is clearly recognizing this model as noted by the error message itself; if it was not, it would not be displaying the model name in the error.

My only wonder is could he enum definition or having a uint id have to do with it? It's outside the class though so I don't see how. Thanks. I'm using EF 6.1.3.

Comment: According to an answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918106/is-it-good-idea-to-use-uint-instead-of-int-as-the-primary-key-in-data-model-clas EF doesn't support having unsigned ints as primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entity Framework doesn't support properties (key or otherwise) of type uint.  Try this experiment:

Change your Todo.Id property to type int (or long).  It will work fine.

Add a non-key property of type uint.  It will still scaffold your migration successfully, but it will completely ignore the uint property, just as if you had excluded it explicitly.

There's a suggestion to add support for uint at [Support unisgned integer](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2085127-support-unsigned-integer-e-g-uint-properties-an), and the EF team says it will be supported in EF7.

Comment: Wow, it definitely should be supported, I've never had to use negative IDs before. Thank you!